# SQL inserting value of a specific column under multple case

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have got a table which I have to insert the description of the contract under different keys of contract.

But when executing, there is a n error near then

Is there any limitation of using syntax set  ?

The below is my SQL

```
declare @i int, @j v nvarchar(MAX)
set @i = 1
while (@i<=8)
begin

   set @j =  case when @i = 1 then 'CR'     when @i = 2  then 'Facebook'      else 'N/A' end

INSERT INTO CostNature (CNKey,  CNNDescription) VALUES (@i , @j );
set @i = @i + 1   
end
```

Comment: did you mean to have the "v" in "@j v nvarchar(MAX)"? If I take the V out then it works fine for me

Comment: Remove v after @j, i think it's a typo

Comment: Thanks
Maybe I should get a can of red bull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Incorrect**

```
@j v nvarchar(MAX)
```

**Correct**

```
@j nvarchar(MAX)
```

Otherwise, all other code is fine.